# Mortar in Mosaic Grout Lines

Tags: tile, mosaic

I installed 100 sq ft of mosaic tile on a floor without cleaning excess mortar as I went. Now I have what seems like 10,000 grout lines that all need to be cleaned. Any advice or suggestions on how to clean them? How clean do they need to be?

Comment: I didn't do mosaic, but I did do some 3x6 tiles in a herring bone pattern with narrow grout lines.  Rather than using the traditional "mortar remover" with the triangle shaped head, I purchased a "backer board cutter" [like this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-Cement-and-Backerboard-Scoring-Knife-with-3-Carbide-Tip-Design-10015/100046621) that has a sharp carbide blade.  Worked good for the narrow lines.

Answer (score 1):

Make a weak acid solution using Muriatic Acid (pool acid) and water in a 5 gal. plastic bucket, 1 cup:gallon. Using gauntlet type chem gloves and eye protection, scrub with acid. Use a grout sponge to rinse and wipe clean, using clean water and wringing frequently. Repeat until all excess mortar and haze is gone.

Note: above method is effective for removing dried smears and haze, solid clumps of dried mortar must be mechanically removed (scraped).